# How to add a type annotation of an intermediate value when combining functions of a type class?

Tags: haskell

Background:
I am working on a declarative compiler. In this course, I am going to write a class to construct an intermediate data structure. After building the data structure, the output can be redendered from the data structure. To simplify for stackoverflow, I created the following code:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Word as W
import qualified Octetable as Oct

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print (buildNRender "123")

data MyData = MyData Integer

data Construction model = Contains model | Error String
    deriving Show

class Builder g where
    build :: String -> (Construction g)
    render :: (Construction g) -> [W.Word8]
    buildNRender :: String -> [W.Word8]
    buildNRender = render . build

instance Builder MyData where
    build s = Contains (MyData (read s :: Integer))
    render (Contains (MyData n)) = Oct.toOctets n
    render (Error _) = []
```

The obvious problem is, 'buildNRender' cannot be part of Builder, because type parameter g is not used at all.

Now, it seems obvious to me that a type class cannot work like this, where an intermediate value in a combination of two or more functions has a type parameter.

The following code makes the intermediate type explicit, and works - but without buildNRender.

```
...

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print (render ((build "123") :: (Construction MyData))

...
```

However, is there an elegant way to define such a DEFAULT method of a class (like 'buildNRender'), and to specify the intermediate type in the context of the caller, like in the following code?

```
...

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print ((buildNRender "123") :: ?(Construction MyData)?)

...
```

Answer (score 6):

> The obvious problem is, `buildNRender` cannot be part of `Builder`, because type parameter `g` is not used at all.

Well, that *used* to be a problem (concretely, the `g` would be *ambiguous*), but isn't anymore because GHC now has extensions that allow working with such parameters.

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}
    
module Main where

import qualified Data.Word as W
import qualified Octetable as Oct

main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        print (buildNRender @MyData "123")

data MyData = MyData Integer

data Construction model = Contains model | Error String
    deriving Show

class Builder g where
    build :: String -> (Construction g)
    render :: (Construction g) -> [W.Word8]

buildNRender :: ∀ g . Builder g => String -> [W.Word8]
-- ∀ (forall) g . introduces the type variable g into scope
-- needs extension AllowAmbiguousTypes
buildNRender = render . build @g -- @g is a Type Application

instance Builder MyData where
    build s = Contains (MyData (read s :: Integer))
    render (Contains (MyData n)) = Oct.toOctets n
    render (Error _) = []
```

Alternatively, without `UnicodeSyntax`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

...

buildNRender :: forall g . Builder g => String -> [W.Word8]
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @leftroundabout: If you dont mind, than I would edit your code to fit to to the original code, and some comments to show for wich part which extension is needed.

Comment: Feel free to edit as you feel fit. (If I don't like it, I can always rollback...)

Comment: @leftroundabout: I dont see a reason to have `buildNRender` a member of class `Builder`. However, since I know there is other solutions where `buildNRender` is member of class `Builder`, would it be correct to say that `buildNRender` cannot be member for this solution with `forall`? Or would it even be possible? Background: I get an error ("Could not deduce (Builder g1)"), when I try.

Answer (score 2):

`AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` are definitely a good approach these days. If, however, you prefer to avoid them, you can use one of two classic techniques: proxy passing or newtype tags.

#### Proxy passing

It's easiest with `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```hs
class Builder g where
    build :: String -> Construction g
    render :: Construction g -> [W.Word8]
    buildNRender :: proxy g -> String -> [W.Word8]
    buildNRender _ = render . (build :: String -> Construction g)
```

The `g` type variable in the class header will scope over the body of the `buildNRender` default definition, and can be used within to resolve the ambiguity. For example,

```
buildNRender (Proxy :: Proxy MyData) "123"
```

The proxy argument passed to `buildNRender` can be any type whose last type argument represents the type you want. The canonical choice is defined in `Data.Proxy`:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
```

If you want to avoid `ScopedTypeVariables` too, then you'll need some sort of helper function. For example, you could write

```
blub :: proxy g -> (String -> Construction g) -> String -> Construction g
blub _ = id
```

and then

```
  buildNRender p = render . blub p build
```

If you need a lot of this sort of thing, you can define more general versions. `blub`'s type, for example, could be rewritten with prefix notation:

```
blub :: proxy g -> (->) String (Construction g) -> (->) String (Construction g)
blub _ = id
```

This leads to a generalization,

```
blub :: proxy g -> f (c g) -> f (c g)
blub _ = id
```

which can be used in exactly the same way.

#### Newtype tagging

To avoid any possible runtime effects of proxy passing at the cost of substantial annoyance in handling, you can import `Data.Tagged`, which defines

```
newtype Tagged s b = Tagged {unTagged :: b}
-- It has a Functor instance
```

Now you can write (with `ScopedTypeVariables`)

```
  buildNRender :: Tagged g (String -> [W.Word8])
  buildNRender = Tagged (render . (build :: String -> Construction g))
```

Without `ScopedTypeVariables`, things are again trickier. One option would be

```
blurble :: f (c g) -> Tagged g (f (c g))
blurble = Tagged

  buildNRender :: Tagged g (String -> [W.Word8])
  buildNRender = (render .) <$> blurble build
```

Call could be:

```
unTagged (buildNRender :: Tg.Tagged MyData (String -> [W.Word8])) "123"
```

Comment: ... so an example call could be `buildNRender (Proxy :: Proxy Int)`. but this also requires a GHC extension? so to avoid any, we would have to actually define a variable like `intProxy :: Proxy Int ; intProxy = Proxy` to be passed to `blub`? that's also a bit annoying...

Comment: @WillNess, no, that requires no extensions. Scoped type variables are only needed when we want to capture a type argument. `Int` is available anywhere.

Comment: I meant the inlined type signature. I thought it needs some extension.

Comment: @dfeuer, thank you. I am going thru to it one by one - to understand. It wil take some time. I like the proxy passing, where buildNRender can belong to the class. I added an example code, if you dont mind.

Comment: @dfeuer, I suppose there no speacial reason to name the function `blub`, is there? If not, for better readability, would `applyProxy` a name that fits the purpose?

Comment: @dfeuer, I found a call for the newtype tagging. It works, but a bit cumbersome. Is there be a better way?

Comment: @WillNess, no, that's standard.

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann, I dunno. There are lots of different ways to "apply" proxies, which makes naming them difficult. The `TypeApplications` way is much more ergonomical than `Tagged` in most cases. `Tagged` mostly makes sense in certain higher-rank situations where you *can't* use type applications and proxy passing has performance or other issues that matter in context.